# For loop exits prematurely when iterating over array. C

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, printf, break

When I try to print the contents of a large enough array (~ > 1000) in a for loop, it exits before iterating over all of the values.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    short size = 5000;
    int arr[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        arr[i] = i;
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Interestingly, the first loop does complete every time. It is the second one which gets truncated.

Output:

```
0
1
...
4998
4999

0
1
...
2578
2579
258
[Process exited 0]
```

The value of the last output can change from execution to execution and seems to be somewhat dependent on the complexity of the function. So when I add more logic the loop tends to break earlier. So adding inside the loop something like

```
for (int j = 0; j < 100; ++J)
    int x = j*j*j;
```

*usually* results in the loop breaking earlier, although the exact point of loop exit appears to be random. When the loop stops iterating the whole program exits, so **no code written after the loop gets executed**.

What's even more confusing is that it will output more values if I increase the size of an array:

```
short size = 10000;
```

Output:

```
0
1
...
7433
7434
[Process exited 0]
```

I run this on linux 64 bit with gcc 10.2.0

Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

UPD: provided some more info

Comment: do you see anything in the syslog when the program terminates?

Comment: What happens with "    int arr[5000];" ?  (The arraySize must be an integer constant)

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2efb56ad9001e574). Belaying the sanity of a 5k-element VLA (why?), what "more logic" are you referring to, and how *exactly* are you running this? Step by step (trivial as it may seem) is important.

Comment: I don't know how to read/use syslog. But journalctl does not report anything in the timespan of the program run. Changing 'short size' to 'const short size' does not make any difference in the output. The program terminates when the loop breaks. So no line of code written after the loop is getting executed.

Comment: Anything interesting running under `strace`? After library setup stuff, I'd expect just a bunch of `write` calls.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille A local array's size does not need to be a constant expression in modern C. You might be thinking of earlier C versions, or of the C++ rule.

Comment: Analysis from the information given suggests that you would get better diagnostics if you put `fflush(stdout)` after every `printf`.

Comment: Where does "[Process exited 0]" come from?

Comment: There's no reason the program should do that. So it's some external factor. CPU overheating, [CPU bug?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/170895/understanding-the-scope-of-intel-hyperthreading-errata-kbl095) or you managed to set ulimit -t by mistake? :) If it's on system-level, something should be visible in the output of `dmesg`. Try also running it under gdb or maybe from a different terminal (maybe it's a bug in the terminal?) or redirected into a file.